# running spark application encouter an error (maven relative)

Tags: apache-spark, maven-2, maven-3

I am trying to figure out how maven works. When I add a dependency to my existing pom.xml and rebuild my spark application project. BUILD SUCCESS I can get from the console. However, when I running the spark application, the spark-shell was not happy and directly give me a message following :

```
Exception : Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com/github/stuxuhai/jpinyin/PinyinFormat
Caused by : ClassNotFoundException : com.github.stuxuhai.jpinyin.PinyinFormat
```

I go to the directory .m2/repo/com/github/stuxuhai/jpinyin/1/.1.1 and jpinyin-1.1.1.jar was there. What happened ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: When does the exception happen? Can you post the entire `spark-submit` command? Can you post how you build the Spark application? Do you use local or cluster mode?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thanks, Jacek. The reason for that is I don't take the external jar to spark classpath. I have solved it by another build command. mvn assembly : assembly.

Comment: Can you make it an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Yeah!  I'd like to. But how can I do and make it an answer ? I think you should put your answer in the following tab and I can make it as an answer ? Okay ?

Comment: Just put your comment as an answer and approve.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Sorry, I can't catch up to you and don't have enough reputation. Only 5. Maybe don't have privilege about it. Will you agree ?